# How to create a vector tiles map with ngx-leaflet (Angular way)?

Tags: angular, vector, leaflet, mapbox-gl-js, ngx-leaflet

Any good recommended angular 6+ supported libraries which can be used to accomplish the following task?

I'm using [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) as the Map.
I wish to create the map with **Vectors rather than Rasters**. [I know that Leaflet doesn’t support vector tiles by default](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/leaflet/), however, you can accomplish via [mapbox-gl-leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet) plugin.

Can anyone recommend me an approach or an appropriate library to accomplish this task using angular 6+?

Comment: Using VectorGrid plugin on Angular 7 would that be ok for you?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Leaflet.VectorGrid plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid). See [ngx-leaflet-starter](https://github.com/haoliangyu/ngx-leaflet-starter/blob/master/src/app/map.service.ts) and the associated [demo](http://haoliangyu.github.io/ngx-leaflet-starter/).

1. Install it via `yarn add leaflet.vectorgrid`
2. Create [binding file](https://github.com/haoliangyu/ngx-leaflet-starter/blob/master/src/typings/leaflet.vectorgrid.d.ts) `src/typings/leaflet.vectorgrid.d.ts` defining API you want to use, eg:

   ```
   import * as L from "leaflet";

   declare module "leaflet" {
     namespace vectorGrid {
       export function slicer(data: any, options?: any): any;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Load your vector tiles, for instance:

   ```
   // add import statement
   import * as L from "leaflet";
   // then call...
   loadGeojson() {
       this.http.get("assets/airports.min.geojson").subscribe(result => {
               this.vtLayer = L.vectorGrid.slicer(result, {
                 zIndex: 1000
               });
               this.vtLayer.addTo(this.map);
       });
   }
   ```