# Present geoJSON data on Leaflet map in Angular

Tags: angular, performance, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to present some geoJSON data on a leaflet map. The geoJSON file is big (60mb) and the performance of the site is terrible when the data is being loaded. The geoJSON is about traffic density and more, so it contains about 230k segments...

What I've tried so far, is to implement `leaflet.vectorgrid` in angular by creating the `leaflet.vectorgrid.d.ts` as it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54388505/10165585). This is the file:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";

declare module "leaflet" {
  namespace vectorGrid {
    export function slicer(data: any, options?: any): any;
  }
}
```

Although the performance is still bad.

This is my code so far:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  MapOptions,
  LatLng,
  TileLayer,
  Map,
  LeafletEvent,
  Circle,
  Polygon
} from "leaflet";

import * as L from "leaflet";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "map-visualization",
  templateUrl: "./map-visualization.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./map-visualization.component.scss"]
})
export class MapVisualizationComponent implements OnInit {
  leafletOptions: MapOptions;
  layersControl: any;
  map: Map;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeMap();
  }

  /**
   * Initializes the map
   */
  initializeMap() {
    this.leafletOptions = {
      layers: [
        new TileLayer(
          "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
          {
            maxZoom: 18
          }
        )
      ],
      zoom: 4,
      center: new LatLng(48.1323827, 4.172899)
    };
  }

  /**
   * Once the map is ready, it pans to the user's current location and loads the map.geojson
   * @param map Map instance
   */
  onMapReady(map: Map) {
    this.map = map;

    if (navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.map.setView(
          new LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
          12
        );
      });
    }

    this.http.get("assets/map.json").subscribe((json: any) => {
      L.geoJSON(json).addTo(this.map);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Return the current bound box
   * @param event Leaflet event
   */
  onMapMoveEnd(event: LeafletEvent) {
    console.log("Current BBox", this.map.getBounds().toBBoxString());
  }
}
```

Finally, the geoJSON is always going to be that big (60mb)... 
So, I was wondering if there is a way to filter the data that is fetched within the current bounding box.

**Note** the file is stored locally for now but later I will fetch it from the API.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I can suggest a solution based on my past implementation, but I'm not sure if you are still looking for a solution.

Comment: @samlu I'm not looking for a solution, I found myself one using [turf](https://turfjs.org/). I'm currently checking if each of my `linesting`s is inside my bbox. It has not the best performance, but it's working. You can write your past implementation though to check if it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach should work natively with leaflet (without relying on another library):

`this.map.getBounds()` - returns `LatLngBounds` - the boundaries (coordinates of the 4 corners) of the map - the "bounding box" - this you are already doing.

`LatLngBounds` has a method called `contains()`, which returns `true` if the value of `coords` is within the bounding box: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#latlngbounds-contains

You can create a method which would be called both from `onMapReady()` and `onMapMoveEnd()` that does something like this:

```
addItemsToMap(items: []): Layer[] {
  const tempLayer: Layer[] = [];

  items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.coordinates) {
      const itemCoordinates = latLng(
        item.coordinates.latitude,
        item.coordinates.longitude
      );
      /** Only add items to map if they are within map bounds */
      if (this.map.getBounds().contains(itemCoordinates)) {
        tempLayer.push(
          marker(itemCoordinates, {
            icon: icon(
              this.markers['red']
            ),
            title: item.description
          })
        );
      }
    }
  });

  return tempLayer;
}
```

In my experience, Leaflet could handle up to ~800 features comfortably. If user experience permits, you can also show a message to the user, asking them to zoom or pan, until the number of features is below the tolerable number.

Note: contains() accepts `LatLng` and `LatLngBounds`. To see if a polyline or a polygon overlaps or "is contained by" a bounding box, either:

- use the centroid and pass as `LatLng`. A polyline/polygon has a `getCenter()` method: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#polyline-getcenter
- "wrap" the polyline into a box as pass as `LatLngBounds`. A polyline/polygon has a `getBounds()` method: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#polyline-getbounds

The two methods will obviously return different results: the centroid/overlap should return more matches.

Comment: Well, this is indeed a good way to check if a point is in the current bounding box, but what I needed is to check if a `linestring` is inside the bounding box. Anyway, I'll find a way to check if it is in. The logic is clear though. Thanks

Comment: @ThPadelis I updated the answer for polylines/polygons.